# Pandas .loc function not finding all matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam working with a project that is converting invoice PDFs to excels and comparing values between two different columns, but iam having trouble with something when comparing values,what iam doing is using .loc function to search for the values of a list in a specific column

This is the code to compare if a value on list is in values column and add to a different DF

```
difference = df_bank.loc[df_bank['value'].isin(list_difference)]
```

This is the bank_df:

```
     Date             Name                   Value
0    25/02/2022             Lorem  C               0.0
1    02/03/2022            Ipsum   C               100.0
2    02/03/2022          Lorem Ipsum   *           16.9
3    02/03/2022            Lorem  C                2454.0
4    02/03/2022            Ipsum                   3732.0
```

This is the list_difference:

```
[0.0, 16.9, 2454.0, 3732.0]
```

But for some reason the difference is only:

```
         Date             Name                   Value
0    25/02/2022             Lorem  C               0.0
3    02/03/2022            Lorem  C                2454.0
4    02/03/2022            Ipsum                   3732.0
```

It doesn't get the value 16.9 for example, even though it is on bank_df

Comment: try converting the column to float data. Everything works. df_bank['Value'] = df_bank['Value'].astype(float)                         And you have value with a small letter.

Comment: Yeah, that solved it, i was using downcast from Pandas, but it think they work differently? Used .astype and functioned perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the column to a float.

```
df_bank['Value'] = df_bank['Value'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're encountering rounding issues, so `16.9` could be really 16.90000001 or something like that.

Maybe you should try:

```
list_difference = np.array(list_difference).round(2)
difference = df_bank.loc[df_bank['Value'].round(2).isin(list_difference)]
```